# Getting PG:UndefinedTable: ERROR: when running migration to add friendships table (In development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to build an app that has users and friendships. I am using Rails 5, Ruby 2.4.0, and PostgreSQL 9.5.6

I'm currently trying to implement  the add friend feature. I have added has_many associations for friendships, and for friends(through friendships, using the class of User).

I have found similar error messages related to not having the table being named created, however in my case the table friends, should just be my user table, aliased as friends.

When I try to run the migration to generate my friendships table I get the following error

```
-- create_table(:friendships)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "friends" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "friendships" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "friend_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e3733b59b7"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_d78dc9c7fd"
FOREIGN KEY ("friend_id")
  REFERENCES "friends" ("id")
)
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/db/migrate/20170311194725_create_friendships.rb:3:in `change'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "friends" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "friendships" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "friend_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e3733b59b7"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_d78dc9c7fd"
FOREIGN KEY ("friend_id")
  REFERENCES "friends" ("id")
)
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/db/migrate/20170311194725_create_friendships.rb:3:in `change'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "friends" does not exist
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/db/migrate/20170311194725_create_friendships.rb:3:in `change'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/disc0ninja/Documents/Udemy/rails/workout-app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Migration created when generating friendship model via:

```
rails g model friendship user:references friend:references
```

Here is the migration file

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :friendships do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :friend, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships, class_name: 'User'

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Do I need to add the association for friends, through friendships in the migration before I run it somehow?

Edit: Added migration file

Comment: The problem seems to be that your migration is trying to add a foreign key to `friend_id` which references a (non-existent) table `friends`. It should probably let the foreign key reference the table `users` instead. Please show how you implemented your migration.

Comment: I updated the post with the migration information.

Comment: in `create_table(:friendships)` Your error is `relation "friends" does not exist`
Include the following in friends.rb
`friend has_many :users, :through :friendship ` and `friend has_many :friendships`.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio adding the associations as you described, gets me the same error when I try to run the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the migration to use index instead of foreign_key seems to have stopped the error message, and allow me the functionality I was after.

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :friendships do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :friend, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```